# Get the parent page title name from a specific page ID number

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page ID number stored in a variable. However I'm trying to access that specific page ID numbers parent page title.

Could someone lead me in the right direction.

Comment: Please include some code of what you have tried so far and what isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try to use the following code:

```
get_the_title(wp_get_post_parent_id($your_post_ID));
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Will mark as correct once its time.

Answer (score 0):

For the current page:

```
<?php
echo empty( $post->post_parent ) ? get_the_title( $post->ID ) : get_the_title( $post->post_parent );
?>
```

If that ID is some others page ID i would say run a query on the DB itself to get that title.